# Symfony2 3.0 / Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Cache\ApcCache not found

Tags: symfony

After upgrade from 2.8 to 3.0, I have issue with APC.

```
[2015-12-05 17:03:05] php.CRITICAL: Fatal Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Cache\ApcCache' not found {"type":1,"file":"/var/www/vhosts/host/httpdocs/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php","line":1102,"level":6143,"stack":[]} []
[2015-12-05 17:03:05] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: "Attempted to load class "ApcCache" from namespace "Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Cache". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?" at /var/www/vhosts/host/httpdocs/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php line 1102 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ClassNotFoundException(code: 0): Attempted to load class \"ApcCache\" from namespace \"Symfony\\Component\\Validator\\Mapping\\Cache\".\nDid you forget a \"use\" statement for another namespace? at /var/www/vhosts/host/httpdocs/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php:1102)"} []
```

How could I fix that? appProdProjectContainer.php symfony generate automatically.

UP:
My composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0"
    },
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `/app/cache/dev` (or `/var/cache/dev` if you're using Symfony 3.0) directory and run Symfony again.

Explanation: As the cache was created with Symfony 2.8, it included the deprecated ApcCache class. Now you updated 2.8 to 3.0 and probably run `php app/console cache:clear`. This means you Symfony 3.0 first has to boot, it errors during this phase as the cache was broken.

Comment: In 3.0 it would be var/cache.  I suspect his app has 3rd party bundles which have not yet been upgraded to 3.x

Comment: Still same error... I'm added my composer.json, I don't have 3rd party bundles.

Comment: PHP version?  Seems strange.  What happens when you install a new project with: composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition s30 "3.0.*"

Comment: @kironet do you by any change use this class yourself? (e.g. in a service definition?)

Comment: PHP version is 5.6.
No, I done nothing by myself in classes. Just installed new 3.0 project, copied my bundles and added them to the AppKernel.

Comment: @kironet ah, this is a bug in Symfony 3. I've send some fixes: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/16865, https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/16866, https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/pull/901

Answer (score 0):

Have you upgraded correctly your `web/app.php` and `web/app_dev.php` while upgrading to Symfony 3.0?

Even if it is the upgrade path from 2.7 to 2.8, you should really have a look at this diff file: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/compare/2.7...2.8#diff-12 (and the same for `web/app_dev.php`).
Make sure these changes are reflected on your files too. You can also directly copy and paste [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/v3.0.0/web/app.php) and [that](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/v3.0.0/web/app_dev.php) in your files.

Make sure you have the following lines too in your `composer.json` files (if not, apply the change and run `composer update` again):

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
}
```